# How to listen for segment value (__/__/___) change in input[type="date"]

Tags: javascript, angular, html

Input[type="date"] returns a value only if all the segments(**/**/___) are filled with proper values. Is there a way to know if any of the segments is filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the values that you **see** (e.g. `05/02/`    ) only exist in the UI layer. The value of the DOM element becomes `""` anytime the parsing as a Date fails, and it is set to `"yyyy-mm-dd"` anytime the parsing as a Date succeeds.

The spec: https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#date-state

Quote regarding parsing/validation:

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid date string, then set it to the empty string instead.